# NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/httpclient/HttpException while making WS call with Axis2

Tags: java, apache-axis, noclassdeffounderror, httpexception

I'm making a soap call with Axis2 1.6.2 (ADB generated classes) and httpclient 4.2.1. for some reason it throws me NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/httpclient/HttpException.

I checked HttpException is in a different package now for HttpClient 4.

Can anyone think of any reason why it throws that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTTP transport in Axis2 1.6.x uses commons-httpclient 3.x. Only Axis2 1.7.x has support for HttpClient 4.x.

Comment: thanks. that's it. i am trying to use 1.7. do you know what i am having this error?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36091540/axis2-1-7-1-wsdl2java-issue

Answer (score 2):

please make sure axis2 jar file is in your CLASSPATH .

Comment: Thanks.    Yes. Axis2 and HttpClient related jars are in the classpath