# Axis2 1.7.1 wsdl2java issue

Tags: apache-axis, wsdl2java

I run `wsdl2java -u -uri` on a wsdl file and java classes it generates throws error `xxx must implement the inherited abstract method adbbean.getpullparser`. I don't think I encountered this issue before.

Why is that?

Answer (score 6):

That means that you are generating code with Axis2 1.7.x, but then try to build it with Axis2 1.6.x or earlier. As explained in the [Axis2 1.7.0 release note](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/release-notes/1.7.0.html), that is not supported.